# "must not be done" vs "must be not done"

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage, phrase-choice, idiomatic-language

> The latest comments **must not be included** in the document.
>
> The latest comments **must be not included** in the document.

I'm not sure whether the selected phrases are correct? What is the way natives speak that?

Comment: what do you think it should be instead?

Comment: See the updated question for an example)

Comment: A less awkward way of phrasing *must be not included* is *must be* ***excluded***.

Answer (score 1):

The first example, "must not be included", is correct. In modern English, finite negations can only be attached to auxiliary verbs ("be" in this instance). That said, both examples would almost definitely be understood by native speakers.

Further reading:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirmation_and_negation
- https://babel.ucsc.edu/~hank/jh.papers/nfneg.pdf
- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/375452/can-we-use-not-after-verbs